# How to convert json data into an accessible array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am getting a JSON list of fonts from Google API and I want to use it in my PHP application.  I need a way to access this JSON object easier.  For example I want to be able to call a font and it's properties easily like so:

```
$font['abc']['variants']
```

... etc.

So the JSON looks like this:

```
$fonts = '
{
 "kind": "webfonts#webfontList",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "webfonts#webfont",
   "family": "Yesteryear",
   "variants": [
    "regular"
   ],
   "subsets": [
    "latin"
   ]
  },
  {
   "kind": "webfonts#webfont",
   "family": "Zeyada",
   "variants": [
    "regular"
   ],
   "subsets": [
    "latin"
   ]
  }
]
}
';
```

And I am using this to parse it into an array:

```
$fonts = json_decode( $fonts, true );
$var_dump( $fonts['items'] );
```

And a var dump of this would show:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'kind' => string 'webfonts#webfont' (length=16)
      'family' => string 'Yesteryear' (length=10)
      'variants' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'regular' (length=7)
      'subsets' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'latin' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'kind' => string 'webfonts#webfont' (length=16)
      'family' => string 'Zeyada' (length=6)
      'variants' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'regular' (length=7)
      'subsets' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'latin' (length=5)
```

So with the above array, I can't easily retrieve the data I want.  So I am not sure if this would mean I have to rebuild the array and if so, how?

Thanks for looking.

Comment: what's the problem with the dump? looks good.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Do you want to replace correlative numeric keys with random string keys to make reading easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to get values : Here you will get the values of all arrays inside `items`

```
foreach($fonts['items'] as $val){

    echo $val['kind'];
    echo $val['family'];

    print_r($val['variants']);
    echo "======================<br>";
}
```

Comment: Right, however I am trying to pull a font and its properties easily without having to loop through it...like an associative array.

Comment: @Rick : I don't know any better option than looping, As you have multiple arrays inside `items`, it will be complicated to fetch each value directly unless you know the exact key.

Comment: So my assumption was correct that I would need to rebuild the array to be associative?

Comment: But I suggest to use loop, because your array looks fine. Your array will be more complicated if you rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:
[Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GFidmD)

Comment: Perhaps my explanation wasn't good enough...Ok for example the user of my application picks a font from a list of 650+ fonts in google via that JSON list...Ok so now my application knows the user wants X font.  So then I would need to pull the X font data out from the array so I can pass it to the google API...But with the array you see above, I can't easily do that with non associative array.  Thus my solution was to rebuild it but that is the question I wanted to ask if that is the best option...

Comment: I think i would go with rebuilding it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this snippet will help you

```
$res1=json_decode($fonts,true);
$res2=$res1['items'];
$count=count($res2);
for($i=0;$i< $count;$i++)
{
    echo $res2[$i]['variants'][0];
}
```